# How can I tell if an AC adapter is compatible with my laptop?

Tags: power-supply

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [charging laptop with a diffrent manufacture charger](https://superuser.com/questions/32372/charging-laptop-with-a-diffrent-manufacture-charger)

How can I tell if an AC adapter is compatible with my laptop?  For example, does the voltage output have to bee the same, or just close?  What power measurements matter?

Comment: possible dupe - http://superuser.com/questions/36311/is-it-safe-to-use-a-power-supply-with-a-different-laptop

Comment: Which is itself a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/32372/charging-laptop-with-a-diffrent-manufacture-charger/

Comment: Yeah, it might be a dupe, but we all used different key words to describe the same thing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Any AC adapter is considered compatible with any device if it has ***all* the following traits**:

- #### The voltage of the adapter has to be identical.

  *It's possible that a voltage can be "close enough" because many devices are built to work within a certain voltage range. But there's no way to know reliably how your device will handle a different voltage.*
- #### The amperage (amps) of the adapter has to be equal or greater than the device.

  *A device draws amperage from an adapter so there has to be at least as much amperage available as the device needs.*
- #### The polarity of the adapter has to be identical.

  *The polarity of your adapter (and device) is usually indicated by a diagram with two circles showing a plus (+) and a minus (-) pointing to the outer plug and the inner plug.*

Of course, the shape of the plug in your device has to match the shape of your adapter so you can plug it in. If you can match all *four* criteria, you should be okay.

Comment: This is the safe and correct answer.  This thread is being used as a dupe target, and many of the new questions are about how far can I deviate from this advice.  Since this thread is, itself, closed as a duplicate, new answers can't be added here.  So let me add a few thoughts to better address the new questions.  **Voltage:** Exact is guaranteed OK.  I would suggest that ~3% should generally be safe as "close enough" (+/- 0.5V at 19V or 20V output).  **Current:** equal or greater is guaranteed OK.  Less can potentially work if its close and you don't push things.  (cont'd)

Comment: The OEM charger may be generic/over-spec'ed, and it's designed for max load and to power and charge concurrently.  With a lower capacity charger, charge the battery while powered off before using it to operate plugged in, and minimize accessories that are powered from the ports.  If an under-powered charger still gets hot, assume it's inadequate.  One **additional caveat:** Some brands check for their own proprietary charger, so just a matching plug doesn't guarantee that the charger will work.

Answer (score 2):

This has been covered before, but you need to ensure:

- the voltage is the same
- the polarity of the tip (of the laptop plug) is the same
- the size and shape of the tip is the same (shape isn't usually an issue as they all tend to be round, but the size might be different).
- the current is greater than or equal to the requirements of the laptop