# How Do I Know Which Replacement AC-Adapter Is Right For Me?

Tags: laptop, ac-adapter

I'm trying to find a replacement AC adapter for my `MSI GS70 Stealth Pro-024`. The original stopped working due to damage to the cord. As I began looking I found a number of options but became dismayed when I noted subtle differences with the specs on the back of my original adapter. Those specs are:

Model: ADP-150VB B
Input: 100-240V, 2.7A, 50-60Hz
Output: 19.5V, 7.7A
More: 150W

I've seen some useful, and very similar posts such as:
[How can I tell if an AC adapter is compatible with my laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/53645/how-can-i-tell-if-an-ac-adapter-is-compatible-with-my-laptop)

These still left me with questions. For example one replacement I found:

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00SPW81EC?keywords=ADP-150vb%20b&qid=1447120935&ref_=sr_1_4&sr=8-4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00SPW81EC)

This has similar specs however for input it has: `120V-240V/ 50-60Hz`; is this acceptable even as mine reads 100V-240V/ 50-60Hz?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Most critical is output voltage must be equal, and amps on the replacement must be equal or greater than the original.  As far as you input voltage question you should be fine if your in the US (120v) or on a 240v system in another country.

Comment: @Tyson is right, input doesn't really matter. But you can find on Amazon enough that do have the same input too. (And that's beside the fact that the seller in your link writes 120-140 while on the picture you see 110-140...)

See for instance this http://amzn.to/1GU7w8s or this http://amzn.to/20Isz4d

Comment: The difference is semantics.  120 and 240 are "nominal" values for votage standards.  The 120 actual voltage is often 110 to 117 and it can vary a bit with demand.  the unit that is labelled 100-240 likely represents the actual voltage range under which it will produce the rated output.  The unit labelled 120-240 likely represents the voltage standards it works with.  But those input values should be equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input doesn't matter regarding laptop chargers. As long as the output matches the output of your charger, the replacement will safely work. The input on the charger is recording what goes into the charger, but we want the output (what the charger sends to the laptop) to be the same.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to get the following: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00OMGQ4DA?keywords=ADP-150vb%20b&pebp=1447120786175&perid=3605J3EK2HGCMG2QGFRH&qid=1447120935&ref_=sr_1_2&sr=8-2, however I noted that this one lists optional output: `19.5V, 7.7A` and also `19V, 7.9A`; how can it have two?

Comment: @Gedalya The charger is actually 7.9A. They just list the 7.7A to show that it can also be used as a replacement for 7.7A chargers. (See the comment made on your question by @Tyson)