# Targus Aftermarket Charger Lower Amperage

Tags: laptop, sony-vaio, charger

I have a Sony Vaio VPCEE42FX that requires 4.7 Amps And 19.5V for proper charging. However, my old charger broke and I found a new aftermarket Targus charger... but the amperage for it is 4.**6** amps. Is it safe to use this charger with normal computer use? However, I do a bit of gaming as well, but I'm not so sure about gaming with this charger, as it could potentially damage my PC's hardware. Should I use this charger? After all, it's the only one I have...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did the 4.7A figure come from?  Is that from the power label on the laptop?  Documentation for the laptop?  What the original charger provided?  The 4.7 figure could be based on worst-case, with things hanging off every USB port at start-up, or a generic charger used for multiple models but overkill for yours.  There are a lot of possibilities.  The 4.6A is pretty close, and I suspect it would be fine, particularly if you aren't maxing out power usage at the time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell if an AC adapter is compatible with my laptop?](http://superuser.com/questions/53645/how-can-i-tell-if-an-ac-adapter-is-compatible-with-my-laptop)

Comment: The proposed dupe has generic advice.  The question adds a layer of "how close is close enough", that isn't really addressed in the other question.

Answer (score 1):

If the **only difference** is 0.1 amps, you should be alright. The laptop only draws what it needs anyway. In most cases, the laptop is not going to draw the maximum the adapter can handle. That 0.1 amperage difference is probably in the margin of error anyway.