# Is there a risk of damaging a laptop with another charger?

Tags: laptop, adapter, charger

Original charger:
Input: 100-240V , 50-60Hz , 1.6A
Output: 19V , 3.42A

New Charger:
Input: 100-240V , 50-60Hz , 1.5A
Output: 19V, 3.42A

Comment: Simple Answer: No :)

Comment: I would say no as the new charger certainly looks like it's electrically compatible (19V 65W), but make sure that the replacement is of good quality. Cheap off-brand chargers will often have poor output quality which can lead to reduced hardware service life.

Comment: Dupe: [How can I tell if an AC adapter is compatible with my laptop?](https://superuser.com/q/53645)

Answer (score 1):

The new charger will work perfectly. The 1.5 vs 1.6 input discrepancy is probably just the efficiency of the charger. They both output the exact same voltage at the exact same amperage, so there is no possibility for damage.

Answer (score 1):

There is risk to damage your laptop if the output V is different to the original one. The output A does not matter if it is bigger or the same value because the A is the maximum current provided by the charger, so if the laptop consumes less amps that can give the charger, nothing happens.

So in resume:

- Make sure the plug is compatible
- Make sure the V is the same
- Make sure the output A is the same of bigger