# Questions about power supply

Tags: power-supply, sound-card

Taking into account the information provided by [this](https://superuser.com/a/53647/360860) answer, in order to power an audio device with the following specifications:

[image]

is it correct to say that I could use a power supply providing an output tension between 9 and 20 volts? Furthermore, since no information about signal amplitude are provided, is whatever amperage sufficient to power the device?

Comment: Isn’t the Traktor Audio 2 supposed to be ISB powered?  You have to determine the amount of Amps the device needs in addition to the amount of Volts.  Just supplying the Volts will be not enough, if this device attempted to draw more Amps than the power supply supports, you would burn out the power supply. Please provide enough information to accurately answer your question

Comment: @Ramhound, yes, this sound card works properly also when is simply connected to a USB port. However, I would like to use it also with a tablet (e.g. an iPad) and, in order to avoid excessive battery power consumption, I am planning to use an external power supply connected to its DC socket.

Comment: I assume you do not have the original power supply in order to determine the ratings of that supply?  Are you able to contact the manufacturer and request the information?

Comment: @Ramhound, it seems that Native Instruments separately provides a power supply with [these](https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/NI23974--native-instruments-ni-23974-18w-power-supply) specifications but I would like to avoid to buy another power supply if I already own a compatible one.

Answer (score 0):

Without the documentation from the manufacturer we can't know **for sure**.  However here is an educated guess based on USB standards.

The amperage is promotional to the voltage.  Meaning 20v is roughly 2x as much as 9v so if it draws 2A and 9v then it will take roughly 1A at 18v.

There is a formula, amps * volts = watts

```
so 2A* 9v = 18w
   1A* 18v = 18w
```

If it has the ability to be USB powered it is very likely that the number of amps required is very low.

USB 2 is 5v at 500ma or 2.5w

USB 3 is 5v at 900ma or 4.5w.

There is a special charging mode where 2-2.4a of current may be delivered.

In this case 2.4*5 = 12w.

Now if it was USB 3.1 there is 100w mode, but your device sounds like it predates this standard.

Since 12w is the absolute highest a USB 3 port is allowed it can't draw significantly more than that.  There is a loss of 20% (possibly higher) depending on the quality of the power supply conversion circuits.

9V at 3a should be more than enough to power this.  Even 9v at 2a is 18w.  As 9v * 1a =9w which is less than the theoretical 12w a USB **could** deliver so I wouldn't risk it.

The power supply you added in the comments is 1.2a at 15v =18w thus roughly 2A at 9v would be fine.  Honestly, I would try and go a bit higher like 2.1 or 2.2 if that is an option.

Thus anything that totals 18-20w and it 9v or greater but less than 20v should be fine.  So on the low end 9v*2 =18 on the high end 20v* 0.9A -18w.

Comment: Okay, I found a Netgear AC-DC power supply providing a 12V * 1.5A = 18W. Would be there some risks while testing it connected to the audio device mentioned above? If yes, which kind of risks?

Comment: There shouldn't be any significant risks.  If it were possible you could hook up a volt meter while its plugged in, and you could verify its still 12v under load.  If the 12v source dropped to 11.4v then you would know there wasn't enough amps.  However, that shouldn't be the case.