# Can I run a Lenovo T440p I7 4600 M (Dual Core) with a 65W power supply

Tags: power-supply, thinkpad

I'm thinking about ordering a T440p with a I7 4600M cpu ... It comes with FHD Display, the nvidia graphics chip and the integrated intel chip. They deliver it with the 90W power supply but i was wondering if it was possible to have a 65W power supply for when you are travelling. What will happen? Will it simply charge slower? Will it charge at all? Will the hardware run slower? Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Slow computer on low wattage charger](http://superuser.com/questions/510042/slow-computer-on-low-wattage-charger)

Comment: might be, but maybe not really, since there its a dell and this is a lenovo, maybe power management is different?

Comment: The make of the power supplies doesn't matter, it's all about the voltage, amperage and polarity.  Also see: [Can I safely charge my laptop with a non-standard, third-party charger?](http://superuser.com/questions/32372/can-i-safely-charge-my-laptop-with-a-non-standard-third-party-charger?lq=1) for more info (plus the links in the answer(s) on the question I originally linked as a dupe).

Comment: thanks for the info. what i mean is, maybe the lenovo machines have a mechanism that simply reduces power usage when the supply is less than 90 watts? or if the lower supply can still charge the laptop (slower than the 90w and not while its running) ... i was hoping for someone who might have tested this.

Answer (score 2):

My T440p's power supply is rated 6.75A and 20V DC secondary, that's 135W, not 90W.

The power consumption depends on what you are doing with it, and if you put a 2nd HDD or SSD into the optical drive bay (which is what I did), connect USB devices, etc.

I plugged it into a Wattmeter. My T440p with the Core-I7 4900MQ, 16GB of RAM, and a 256GB and a 1TB SSD draws between 30 and 40 Watts on the primary side with light load, like browsing and word processing. This is while on a wired Ethernet connection. But it jumps around quite a bit.

If you run benchmarks, it will certainly max out the 65W power supply. Reviewers say that the max power consumption with load is over 70W. If office work is all you do, 65W may suffice, even after factoring in the efficiency of the power supply that I would expect to be in the 80% to 90% range.
By the way, the T440p has new rectangular power connectors. If you were hoping to reuse a power supply from last year, forget it!

I ordered a port replicator from Lenovo with it that also came with the big power supply. Yes, they are big and heavy. I would not take a chance and buy a smaller one for mine.