# Will this charger/adapter work for my son's laptop?

Tags: laptop, compatibility, adapter, charger

thanks in advance for your help. I mentioned most of what was on each adapter, I know some will not be of any help but didn't want to miss anything.

His computer model is: ASUS G47VW-BHI5N43
The original adapter (the one that was packed with his brand new computer) shows the following values: 
Model ADP180 HB D
Input 100-240V ~ 2.25A 50-60Hz
Output 19V 9.5 A
Roman numeral value "V"
C.C.: B REV. 3
S/N H00W2AN04FL

The one that a seller has on ebay list for this same computer model shows the following values:
(It is OEM ASUS adapter/charger and otherwise appears exactly like the original)
Model ADB-150NB D 
Input 100-240V ~ 2.0A 50-60Hz
Output 19.5V - 7.7A
Roman number value "V"
C.C. A  REV. 3
S/N  W6W0944061108

The both show N193V85, not sure what that is.

It would be helpful to know whether or not this would work (and knowing why or why not would be even better)!

Thank you!

Comment: No; It will not work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I safely charge my laptop with a non-standard, third-party charger?](http://superuser.com/questions/32372/can-i-safely-charge-my-laptop-with-a-non-standard-third-party-charger), http://superuser.com/questions/53645/how-can-i-tell-if-an-ac-adapter-is-compatible-with-my-laptop?lq=1, http://superuser.com/questions/36311/is-it-safe-to-use-a-power-supply-with-a-different-laptop?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will be enough. As you can see, the original router has an output of 19V - 9.5 A (so 180.5W). The new one has an output of 19.5V -7.7A (so 150.15W). The new one isn't capable of delivering as much as energy, so the computer might not be able to function properly. Additionnally, 19.5V is slightly more than 19V so it might damage the computer (though I doubt that 0.5V would really be dangerous).

Answer (score 0):

A perfect match would be if the input and output matched for both current (measured as amperage, and abbreviated as A) and voltage (V).  As others have alluded to, multiplying the two results in a measure of power, or wattage (W).

In this case, since the second charger mentioned has a slightly higher voltage, and lower amperage, the total wattage is lower.

In general, you can get away with higher current, as what ever is charge will regulate the current (this is why you can use a high current iPad charger with an iPhone and not damage the phone).  I'm not sure about higher voltage.

This charger might work (though it may charge the laptop slower than the factory provided model).  Personally, I'd look for a closer fit in matching current and voltage.