# charging laptop with a different adapter charger

Tags: laptop, power-supply, adapter, battery, ac-adapter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [charging laptop with a different manufacturer's charger](https://superuser.com/questions/32372/charging-laptop-with-a-different-manufacturers-charger)

I have lost this [adapter](http://www.computerbasement.co.uk/toshiba-satellite-a300-15b-ac-adapter-75w-19v-3-95a-charger.html),

- Output Voltage: 19V
- Output Current: 3.95A
- Input Voltage: 100-240V
- Wattage : 75W
- Pin Size: 5.5mm Outer x 2.5mm internal

But I have this [one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004SLQOMA),

- Output: DC19V 3.42A
- Power: 65W Max

Can I use the second adapter instead of first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm - possibly. Assuming the connector is the same size and polarity, it should be absolutely OK to charge when the laptop is powered off, but if in use and under heavy load then this might put a strain on the adapter.