# Using a laptop power adaptor with higher voltage but lower power

Tags: laptop, power-supply

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Charging laptop with non-original charger](https://superuser.com/questions/32372/charging-laptop-with-non-original-charger)
>   [Is it safe to use a power supply with a different laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/36311/is-it-safe-to-use-a-power-supply-with-a-different-laptop)

I've recycled a acer laptop from a friend, but original power adapter is lost.

I'm planning to use a spare dell adapter.

Laptop requirements : 19v, 4.74A
Dell adapter : 19.5v, 4.62A

I will not using the battery at all, so I guess that power consumption will be a bit fewer than specified.

Is there an electrical risk ? or fire risk ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it safe to use a power supply with a different laptop?](http://superuser.com/questions/36311/is-it-safe-to-use-a-power-supply-with-a-different-laptop) also see [Charging laptop with non-original charger](http://superuser.com/questions/32372/charging-laptop-with-non-original-charger), [Can I use a charger with less Ampere than the original?](http://superuser.com/questions/425250/can-i-use-a-charger-with-less-ampere-than-the-original?lq=1).

Comment: I've seen some of them. Just wanted to be sure that more voltage IS REALLY forbidden. Guess answer is yes.