# Charger of less output ampere than device?

Tags: networking, router, battery, nas, charger

I know the cases where the cable has more output amperes, [here](https://superuser.com/q/600401/2005) and [here](https://superuser.com/q/425250/2005), but I am interested in if you can use cables with less output amperes with the devices. 
I have an universal charger *[Vivanco PAU 1500](http://www.vivanco.de/Startseite/Produkte/Energie/Netzteile-und-Ladeadapter/Universal/vivanco-27835-universal-netzteil.html?id=nsession)* which has 1500 mA / 5V. 
I have two devices

- [Buffalo NAS LS-WSX1.0TL/R1](http://www.buffalo-technology.com/products/storage-devices/consumer-nas/linkstationtm/linkstation-trade-mini/) 5V / 2.6A
- [D-link DIR-645](http://support.dlink.com/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DIR-645) 5V / 2.5A (I have a cable 5V / 2.5 A for this but I would like use it for Buffalo)

So I would like to use the configuration

- Buffalo NAS LS-WSX 5V / 2.6A (5V / 2.5A cable here). **Is this 0.1A difference enough significant here?**
- D-link DIR-645 5V / 2.5A (5V / 1.5A cable here). **What do you think about this 1.0A difference?**

The problem is that both cables are too little for both devices. 
I am worried that the cables and their resistances can break if I use them here. 
Can you use a charger less output ampere than the device needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should never use a charger with less amperes then the device "requires". The amount used varies during use depending on load but may go up to what it lists. If your charger can not handle that then you could end up in a situation where you over-tax the charger resulting in a fire.

Normally the cable is included (or even built-in) when you buy the charger and the specifications on the charger covers the cable as well.

When buying a charger you need to look at:
1. If it gives Direct Current (DC) or Alternating Current (AC).
2. The voltage is equal to what device wants (fixed during use, does not vary).
3. The physical connector fits the device.
4. The amperage is equal or higher then the device requires (higher is fine).

Comment: Don't forget polarity! Assuming it's DC.

Answer (score 1):

The cable is not the issue. The power supply (what you're calling the "charger") is the issue.

In the first case with the Buffalo device you are probably ok.

For the second case, a device that is designed to work with a 2.5A supply but you're only giving it 1.5A? I wouldn't count on it working. The attempt might result in a damaged power supply, too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is very difficult to find 2.6 A / 5V cable anywhere for my Buffalo. Any idea how to solve this? There are 70W and 90W universal charges in the shop too which are designed for laptops, however. I think they are not the way to go.

Comment: Higher amperage with the same voltage is fine. So if you use a 3A or a 5A charger, at 5V, you'll be ok.

Comment: @Masi Cry Havok is correct. Your best answer is to keep the Dlink power supply with the Dlink device and get a 3A or higher supply for the Buffalo.