# Charger has fuse busted, could I use this other charger? Details inside

Tags: laptop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [charging laptop with a different manufacturer's charger](https://superuser.com/questions/32372/charging-laptop-with-a-different-manufacturers-charger)

My broke charger outputs at 19V, 4,74A

The other older charger outputs at 8.5, however 5,65A

I am unsure of the correlation between amps and volts, it's not exactly in my line of study.

Would I be capable of using the older charger?

Comment: Eh, never mind, forgot to check the voltage, it has different charges.

Answer (score 3):

No.

You should use same voltage, and same or bigger amper.
Don't use bigger voltage. If you use smaller voltage (like you mentioned) it won't work.
If you use bigger voltage it will/can kill your device which you want to charge.
Bigger amper is ok, lower amper means the charger will hot, very hot, then die.

Comment: Higher output will not affect much as the device will consume only as it required. But lower will affect.