# Are laptop power adapters Interoperable?

Tags: laptop, power-supply

Let's consider two AC power adapters from different brands (e.g. one from HP and another from Dell), with **identical** electrical specifications (voltage, power) and of course with similar plugs. Would such adapters be interchangeable, i.e. would the HP adapter power the Dell laptop, and inversely ?

Behind this question : is there some kind of data exchange between modern adapters (*smart* adapter ?) and laptops that enable a laptop to recognize the make of the adapter ? If so, what kind of networking is used, and is it possible to hack it ?

Comment: No.  The connectors are often not interchangeable.  Which is the reason third-party manufactures sell power adapters with multiple connectors.

Comment: I've successfully used random homemade 19V adapters with Asus. However Dell for example often include a "legitimate Dell product" check somehow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I safely charge my laptop with a non-standard, third-party charger?](http://superuser.com/questions/32372/can-i-safely-charge-my-laptop-with-a-non-standard-third-party-charger)

Comment: Possible duplicate focus on electrical/plug geometry issues. This question is more focused on digital communication between laptops and adapters. Maybe the question should be edited to reflect that more.

Comment: @grawity see this...http://www.laptop-junction.com/toast/content/inside-dell-ac-power-adapter-mystery-revealed and this...http://hackaday.com/2014/03/03/hacking-dell-laptop-charger-identification/ and this...http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16047/3-contact-laptop-power-supply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With an identical connector, equal voltage and at least the same max amperage, with no special gimmicky charger communication, sure.

In reality though, most manufacturers will have their own connector styles, and whilst most are 19v, some are .5 increments above or below.

Regarding the Dell charger communication, yes, basic information is passed using (in some cases, I can't speak for all) the [1-Wire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-Wire) protocol, which has been reverse engineered as can be seen [here](http://hackaday.com/2014/03/03/hacking-dell-laptop-charger-identification/).

Several generic brands of charger exist, usually with a slider to select the correct voltage and several different tips to connect to the laptop. These usual don't include this communication and can cause problems such as not powering the machine or not charging the battery, although they would actually be capable of doing so without this communication.