# Laptop Adapter Input versus output

Tags: adapter, laptop

It is reasonable to say I am a total amateur when it comes to this sort of thing.

Anyway my MSI laptop adapter died and I had to buy a new OEM one. Unfortunately it takes a long time to ship so I also had to buy a replacement one which is not OEM from the following website.

http://www.nextdaypower.com/msi-gt60-0ng-294us-150w-replacement-ac-adapter-charger-power-supply-cord-moreinfo.html?gclid=CMylxcbSt8wCFUZbhgodHCYNMg

In the meantime I need to know if this will work to replace my MSI one which has the following specs compared the to replacement one.

After all the research I did I am still worried about the INPUT Amps on the dead OEM adapter being higher than the INPUT amps on the new replacement one.

MSI dead adapter:

Input: 100-240V ~ 2.7A 50-60Hz
Output: 19.5V ~ 7.7A

New replacement adapter:

Input: 100-240V ~ 1.64A 50-60Hz
Output: 19V ~ 7.9A

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: The input current is pretty much irrelevant. The fact that it is lower for a similar output just means it is more efficient. All you need to ensure is that (a) the voltage/frequency of the input match your country, (b) the output voltage is correct (19V vs 19.5V should make little difference), and (c) the output current capability is sufficient for the device (i.e. same or higher than what it came with).

Comment: Okay thank you - I was aware of the rest being okay but wasn't sure which Amp was important if not both. I didn't want to risk damaging any of the internal laptop parts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I safely charge my laptop with a non-standard, third-party charger?](http://superuser.com/questions/32372/can-i-safely-charge-my-laptop-with-a-non-standard-third-party-charger)